# R- mean for 10 variables by 10 variables

Tags: r

I would like to compute the mean of a variable `Volume`, for the 10 first observations, and then the mean for the 10 next observations, etc.. until the last observation. 
I thought I would need the `Aggregate` function, but I don't know how to group the observations 10 by 10.

Thanks a lot in advance !